# WMI gives Generic Failure when using non-admin user for class Win32_DiskDrive

Tags: wmi

I have gave [appropriate permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771551(v=ws.11)) for non admin account also user is added in "Distributed COM Users" group.

When trying to access `Win32_DiskDrive` or `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` class, I'm getting `Generic Failure` error. Is any extra permission is required?

- Same is working, if I'm using admin account.
- Other class like `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` giving result using non-admin account

  ```
     if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
              {
                  ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
                  {
                      Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                      Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
                      Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                      Username = username,
                      Password = password
                  };

                  var managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + assetNameOrIpAddress + @"\root\cimv2", connectionOptions);
                  managementScope.Connect();
                  managementObjectSearcher.Scope = managementScope;
              }
  ```

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data from a local or remote computer? which OS are you using?

Comment: Remote computer. Mainly issue with WIN2K8 & WIN7 machines

Comment: Have you granted `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` ? [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Services/service-security-and-access-rights)

Comment: what is this, how to grant? Is this required for OS 7, as I'm not seeing any issue with OS like 2k16

Comment: how do you write your code? c# /powershell/ other?

Comment: it's C# code, I'm using

Answer (score 0):

You should add the right privileges

```
       ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
       connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
       //Add AuthenticationLevel that suits your need
       connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; 
       connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

       ManagementScope scope =
  new ManagementScope("MANAGEMNET_PATH"
, connOptions);
       scope.Connect();


       ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
           "YOUR QUERY");
       ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
           new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
```

Comment: Thanks @styx, I'm also using the same code. also sending user/pass and machine ip to fetch data for remote node (question is update with code). When I'm passing admin user/pass, it's working but not working with non-domain user.

Comment: please check using wbemtest that you can access the information from remote machine.

Comment: Yes. connection is good. WMI class like 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' giving result, but class like `Win32_DiskDrive` or `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` giving `Generic Failure` error.